# How to display pdf files in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display pdf files in the application. When I am uploading files and before uploading, I am showing preview using  tag and it is displaying properly. But when I am receiving data from the backend, that time I am showing all the media, everything is getting displayed properly, e.g. images and videos. But when I am adding documents into  tag, white space is displayed.

Code for preview :

```js
            {data.documents &&
              data.documents.map((doc, id) => (
                <Card>
                  <CardHeader
                    action={
                      <IconButton
                        style={{ float: "right" }}
                        onClick={(doc) =>
                          dispatch({ type: USER_DOCUMENT_DELETE, payload: id })
                        }
                      >
                        <CloseRounded color="secondary" />
                      </IconButton>
                    }
                  />

                  <iframe
                    width="200"
                    height="150"
                    title={doc.url}
                    src={doc.url}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography>{doc.name}</Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              ))}
```

code for displaying data:

```js
   {reducedDocuments &&
              reducedDocuments.map((document) => (
                <Card
                className={classes.postMedia}
                onClick={() => {
                  dispatch({
                    type: SHOW_POST_MEDIA_PREVIEW,
                    payload: {
                      id: post.id,
                      showPreview: true,
                    },
                  });
                }}>
                   <iframe
                   
                    src={process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_FILE_PREVIEW + document.file_name}
                  />

                </Card>
              ))}
```

for src I have given the .env variable, I am receiving an array of objects with filename, which contains the path to the backend folder's media folder and specific file name.

Comment: You can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf to display pdfs.

Comment: I don't want to use external library. Is there any other way?

Comment: React is an external library. Why are you adamant to not use another one?

Comment: Application is becoming heavier, I already have several packages installed. That's why I am not using any package

Answer (score 1):

```html
<object width="100%" height="400" data="Put your pdf url here" type="application/pdf">   </object>
```

You can use `<object>` tag to render a pdf file.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp